# CSS turn cells into buttons

Tags: html, css

I have a table with some hover css and hrefs in each cell. I want to make it so if you click anywhere in the cell, it will click the href inside of said cell, I don't really care how sloppy this is, I just want to be able to turn these cells into buttons.
I'm not sure where to start so I can't really include what I tried. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the table with the hover CSS:

```css
div[class*="et_pb_tab_"] td:hover{
    background: #0073a5 !important;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
div[class*="et_pb_tab_"] td:hover span{
    color: #fff !important;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
 <div class="et_pb_tab clearfix et_pb_tab_5 et-pb-active-slide" style="z-index: 1; display: block; opacity: 1;">
<div class="et_pb_tab_content">
 <h2 style="text-align: left;"><b>Table</b></h2>
  <table style="border-color: #AAA; height: 389px; background-color: #fff;" border="#595959" width="970" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
   <tbody>
    <tr style="border-color: #595959; height: 24px;">
     <td style="border-color: #aaaaaa; height: 24px;">
      <h5>
       <a href="example.com">
        <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #1166dd; text-decoration: underline;">Row 1</span></span>
       </a>
      </h5>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-color: #595959; height: 24px;">
     <td style="border-color: #aaaaaa; height: 24px;">
      <h5>
       <a href="example.com">
        <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #1166dd; text-decoration: underline;">Row 1</span></span>
       </a>
      </h5>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-color: #595959; height: 24px;">
     <td style="border-color: #aaaaaa; height: 24px;">
      <h5>
       <a href="example.com">
        <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="color: #1166dd; text-decoration: underline;">Row 1</span></span>
       </a>
      </h5>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Removed jsfiddle and added the SO snippet as per mod's suggestions.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Code on jsfiddle can change or disappear helping no one in the future.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript or JQuery?

Comment: @Rob Sorry, I literally had no idea where to start on this... What do you suggest I do to make this question better?

Comment: You won't be able to transform the table cells into buttons without messing up the layout of your table.  You should be able to append buttons inside of the table cells, however.

Comment: Just copy the html, css and javascript here into your question and put it in code tags. Better, you can create a snippet which will run here, just like a fiddle.

Comment: Re "I don't see a reason to post code here to accompany the JSfiddle 
because it will just be repetitive":  one of the deletion options here is for questions with not enough information to reproduce the problem *within the body of the question itself*.  External links can rot.  jsfiddle can be a nice addition (though largely redundant, now that SO snippets do exactly the same thing) but it's not sufficient as the whole question.

Comment: @Rob I've met the requirements based on the hold, can this be put back now? The info is in the question and the problem is clearly stated of what desired behavior I want.

Comment: I submitted for re-opening but I can't do it on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

CSS:

```
.table td{
  position: relative;
}

.table a{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ls26x5ed/5/

Comment: Anyway to do this while still keeping the text in the middle of the cell?

Comment: Hey @Kushtrim, Turns out this does not work on IE 11, Do you have any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: @DylanGrove Try adding .table td h5{ height: 100%;}. It seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Add position relative to your `td` then make your `a` height and width (100%) to fit your `td` .

```
td {
  position: relative;
}

td a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Anyway to do this while still keeping the text in the middle of the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<td onclick="window.location='http://www.demo.com'">My Button</td>

and then add to the css:

td {
cursor:pointer
}
```